# How to apply proptable() to all the factor variables in R

Tags: r, lapply, data-manipulation

I have a data set with many factor variables at different levels. How I can print out a `proptable()` for each factor variable efficiently. The expected answer is a data frame or table. Many thanks in advance.

```
df <- mtcars[, c("am", "gear")]
df$am <- factor(df$am); df$gear <- factor(df$gear)


prop.table(table(df$am))
prop.table(table(df$gear))
```

Comment: You don't want `prop.table(table(df))`? Or `margin.table(table(df), margin = 1:2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with sapply?

```
sapply(df, function(x) if("factor" %in% class(x)) {prop.table(table(x))})
```

E.g. when prop.table(table(df)) throws an error:

```
library(palmerpenguins)

prop.table(table(penguins))
#Error in table(penguins) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

sapply(penguins, function(x) if("factor" %in% class(x)) {prop.table(table(x))})
#$species
#x
#   Adelie Chinstrap    Gentoo 
#0.4418605 0.1976744 0.3604651 

#$island
#x
#   Biscoe     Dream Torgersen 
#0.4883721 0.3604651 0.1511628 

#$bill_length_mm
#NULL

#$bill_depth_mm
#NULL

#$flipper_length_mm
#NULL

#$body_mass_g
#NULL

#$sex
#x
#   female      male 
#0.4954955 0.5045045 

#$year
#NULL
```